# Error inflating class TextView when I try to set background of TextView

Tags: textview

I use RecyclerView to fetch data . In Adapter is Error of inflating class TextView. When I don't set background, everything works well, but how is it possible to avoid this error?

```
           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_item_message_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="message"
            android:background="@drawable/message_item_background_sender" // this line causes problem
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that background drawable resource was in drawable-v24 folder. I moved it to the drawable folder and it works :)